# Fatal error: json.h: No such file or directory #include <json.h> and I am using WSL

Tags: c++, json, include, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jsoncpp

I am having trouble using the header files from jsoncpp in my program. I am trying to include the library globally through the use of a makefile CFLAGS, but its hard for me to figure out why its not working. This is what I have so far:
[image: Error Code I receive]
[image: Location of Jsoncpp header files]
[image]

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I downloaded WSL and jsoncpp through the ubuntu terminal. When I tried running the make file, it said the given error. So I found the path to the files VSCode could not find and I tried to include it the make file. That did not work.

I also tried using VSCode's quick fix option that allowed me to edit its include path. But that didn't work either after I added it.

Comment: You added `.../jsoncpp` to your include path, but `json.h` is found in `.../jsoncpp/json/` directory. Either change include path or `#include "json/json.h"` instead.

Comment: I tried adding/jsoncpp/json into the make file and it sitill produced the error. So next, i kept that the same, but I also added the #include "json/json.h" which almost worked. I had to do #include <jsoncpp/json/json.h> for it to work. Although if possible, I would prefer to use just <json.h>. Is there a different way to do this than what I am doing?

Comment: Uhm, I know little makefile, but quick duckduckgoing told me that variable for C++ flags is `CXXFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`. And that should then have `-I/user/include/jsoncpp/json`